# Как создать JSON-файл из моих данных? (VS С++ Boost Json)

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-2015, boost

Как создать JSON-файл из моих данных? (VS С++ Boost Json). Я вообще не знаю как это сделать.

Мне нужен JSON вот такого типа:

```
{
  "track": {
    "Wheels": {
      "Wheel": [
        {
          "start_pos": "10",
          "end_pos": "25"
        },
        {
          "start_pos": "22",
          "end_pos": "78"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Brakes": {
      "Brake": [
        {
        "start_pos": "10",
        "midl_pos": "25"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

C++:

```
#include "boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp"
#include "boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using boost::property_tree::ptree;

struct wheel
{
    string start_pos;
    string end_pos;
};

struct brake
{
    string start_pos;
    string midl_pos;
};

int main() 
{
    string tr = "track";
    string ws = "Wheels";
    string bs = "Brakes";

    struct wheel w1;
    w1.start_pos = "10";
    w1.end_pos = "25";

    struct wheel w2;
    w2.start_pos = "22";
    w2.end_pos = "78";

    struct brake b1;
    b1.start_pos = "10";
    b1.midl_pos = "25";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Боюсь у вас проблема: boost::property_tree предназначен для хранения данных только одного типа (строк). Для хранения int он использует преобразование строки в число, по месту запроса данных. (и обратное , по месту записи данных). Т.е. в его объектной структуре не хранится тип значений. Поэтому он всегда записывает данные как `"start_pos": "10",`,   а не `"start_pos": 10,`. Если хотите иметь строго фиксированный вид документа, используйте специализированные библиотеки для работы с JSON. Например, Boos.json: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/quick_look.html

Comment: Если вопрос по Boost Json, то непонятно, при чем тут Property Tree и еще парсер.

Comment: Вопрос. уже не актуален. всем спасибо